# How should an IMAP4rev2 client associate untagged responses for multiple pipelined IMAP commands?

Tags: go, email, gmail, imap, email-client

rfc 9051 defines [Multiple Commands in Progress (Command Pipelining)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9051#name-multiple-commands-in-progre)

- pipelining allows the client to send another command without waiting for the completion result response of a command
- IMAP uses tags to uniquely identify each command sent from the client
- IMAP has untagged responses that the server may send eg. one for each message affected

.

**How can the IMAP client properly associate such untagged response with any of several pending commands?**

- for example, the client may concurrently send multiple identical commands with different arguments and may then possibly receive indistinguishable identical untagged responses
- One legacy imap client broadcasts untagged responses to all pending commands which likely violates integrity [mxk Go IMAP](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mxk/go-imap/imap) 2015
- All other Go clients as of 2024 has proven to be inoperable junk, and there are many, mostly miserable forks of mxk
- Is it so that the server may execute commands in parallel and out of order but sends all responses for one command in an uninterrupted sequence prior to responses to another command?
- The standard only preoccupies with aspects of previous bugs, ie. one command re-sequencing messages, not how concurrency integrity can be guaranteed
- There is always a failure source by multiple concurrent clients using the server so there will never be guaranteed error-free operation

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on why you want to associate the untagged responses with commands.

The answer to the perhaps most common variant of the question is: Parse the untagged responses as you receive them and store them in RAM as structured information, and when you receive a tagged response, look up the relevant information in that data structure.

For example, if the RFC says that you should've received such-and-such `FETCH` responses by the time you receive the tagged response to your command (e.g. `UID STORE`), parse the `FETCH` messages when they arrive and store the per-message information in a data structure, and when you handle the tagged response, look up the messages in that data structure and return the information from it. You might say that this doesn't associate *untagged responses* with tagged responses, but rather the *information* within the untagged responses. Yes. That's right.

This approach works well for all of IMAP except `SEARCH`.

Comment: This is the best-effort sunny-day approach used by all the code I reviewed that works most of the time. This question is about how a guaranteed outcome can be achieved, that with certainty associates an untagged response that is the result of a client command back to the correct command and no other. The approach is increasingly likely to fail as environments get more multi-threaded and parallel. Go is more likely to use many threads, pipelining and bare nanoseconds between commands, this is why most or all imap-code used in Go quickly becomes garbage

Comment: Uhm, I fear you have an unrealistic picture of how IMAP works. IMAP has strict rules for what happens before and after. If you don't understand those rules you're not going to draw correct conclusions from your reviews. IMAP's notions of before and after strictly match sequence in the TCP connection, nothing more, nothing less. The way to get a guaranteed outcome is to pay attention to sequence in the TCP connection.